# Python Recursive Object Creation

Tags: python, algorithm, class, graph-algorithm

I'm trying to optimize my maze generation algorithm. At the moment i have a list of sets of nodes and a list of nodes themselves. Nodes are stored as (x,y) tuples. At the beginning each set contains only one node. I pick a random border between two nodes and check if they are in the same set. Here's the problem - i have to iterate through the list of sets and look at every single item until i find the set which contains given node/nodes. I want to be able to access sets as a property of Node class, but also i want my sets to contain objects of "Node" class and i run into this:

```
class Node:

   def __init__(self, xy:tuple, group:set):
       self.xy = xy
       self.group = group

node = Node((10, 10),{Node(10, 10),{Node(10, 10),{... and so on }}})
```

How do i create such a relation so that i can access sets as **node.group** and at the same time **group** property would point to the needed set with other Node objects without recursion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you wanted ?

```
class Node:

    def __init__(self, xy:tuple):
        self.xy = xy
        self.group = None

    def set_group(self, group:set):
        if  self.group is not None:
            self.group.remove(self)
        group.add(self)
        self.group = group

node1 = Node((1,1))
node2 = Node((2,2))

group1 = set()
group2 = set()

node1.set_group(group1)
node2.set_group(group2)
```

Comment: Yes, thank you, it did help indeed! I got to put a little bit extra stuff in it but it's working just fine. I'm kinda disappointed i didn't figure it out myself :(
Thank you **A LOT** again

Comment: Just to put it into perspective of how much you helped me - the time increased from 45 sec for 1500x1500 jpg image to 15 sec for the same image. God bless you :D